# First time uploading website,how to make default web page?

Tags: html, asp.net, vs-web-site-project

i created a website using asp.net visual studio 2010 express
today i purchased a hosting program with plesk 11.

> on the welcome email of the hosting services i got this line: "please be sure that your homepage is saved as an "index" file e.g., index.htm, index.html, etc

all my website is .aspx files!
also my homepage is using a master page!

they help support couldn't help me.
so i ask you can i just rename it to index.aspx and upload it as it is?

Comment: Are you sure they support ASP.Net?  Also renaming the file should be okay if you rename your "Default.aspx" to "Index.aspx" however I wonder if you've tried uploading it as Default.aspx yet?

Comment: The best way to find out is to try ;). But if your hosting company support ASP, they should make default.aspx your default homepage

Comment: didn't upload any files yet,i don't want to make a mess there.

Comment: "Asp.Net 2.0 & Asp.Net 4.0 with MSSQL 2008" support

Comment: How should i upload the files? all the directory together? or each file by itself?

Answer (score 2):

Open your web.config file and set the following property in it.

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Path of your Page" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```